# Android Best Pratice to reuse code and layout

Tags: android, json

I've been reading about the include tag on xml, fragments to use on layout for smartphone and tablets but I'm getting more confused than getting a solution to my problem.

My App has 4 screens.

1 - You login and it download info from a json

2,3,4 - From login, Activity 2 load (A list with custom adapter), where you can click one of 2 images to jump to 3rd and 4th activity.

I need now to create the activity 1, 2, and 3 again with different JSONs being parsed, with 1 and 2 having the same layout of the existent ones and 3 with a different layout.

The code I need for them to work is(or can be) the same (Download Task with AsyncTask, button click listeners, etc) I already have for those activities.

I think it's not a goot pratice to copy basically the same getView method, for example, and paste on a new class, right? The buttons wouldn't work on the second range of screens for example.

So, what approach should I take that isn't copy and paste code and change things manually?

Sorry for the newbie question.

If needed I can provide code.

PS 1: I've already did tests with include on xml and copy code but that doesnt look professional

PS 2: Is fragments only for different screens like tablet or I could make something with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's several questions, so here's several answers, including to some un-asked questions:

- To the greatest extent possible, strive to remove as much code as possible from your Activities, Fragments, etc. If it doesn't have anything to do with the Android lifecycle or actually putting something on the screen (e.g. parsing JSON), put it in a "plain old java" class. Also, this way, you can share the functionality among Activities.
- IMHO, you should never use an AsyncTask, for any reason. They're used with an Activity or Fragment, but don't respect the Fragment or Activity lifecycle, so are often the cause of crashes that can be difficult to diagnose. Use something synchronized with the lifecycle, like a Loader. Or go the RxJava route, where Subscribers can be canceled at the appropriate point in the Activity/Fragment lifecycle.
- Fragments can be good for code re-use, but they have a slightly different lifecycle from Activities, so they can be difficult to work with, so use them sparingly and be careful. If you're doing it just to re-use a bit of UI (but not behavior), a layout "include" is probably better. For behavior, a custom View class can be a good alternative to a Fragment.
- Don't do HTTP / REST access yourself, using primitives like HTTPUrlConnection. There are a lot of corner cases that are going to get you into trouble. Use one of the several really good open-source libraries that are built for this purpose. I highly recommend Retrofit.

Comment: Contrary of what you may think this is not a vague answer my friend. You, on simple words, solved many problems I had in my mind. With your experienced advice I can already think of better ways to code(don't use HHTPUrlConnection and AsyncTasks anymore, for example). I appreciate it, thank you very much. Have a nice day xD